# LNK file Location wrong

Tags: vb.net

I'm new here. In my Game List project I wanted to add the open shortcut file location feature to the right-click plug-in. In some places it works correctly but it shows a file path that is not in a shortcut!

```
        Dim strPath = ListBox3.SelectedItem ' C:\Users\KARA\Documents\OYUNLAR\PUBG MOBILE.lnk
        If System.IO.File.Exists(strPath) Then ' True = OK
            Dim shell As WshShell = New WshShell()
            Dim link As IWshShortcut = CType(shell.CreateShortcut(strPath), IWshShortcut)
            MessageBox.Show(link.TargetPath) ' Result: False = ("C:\Program Files (x86)\TxGameAssistant\AppMarket\AppMarket.exe")
' it True = "C:\Program Files\TxGameAssistant\AppMarket\AppMarket.exe"
        End If
```

video:
https://youtu.be/8bNb2pYGmq0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I COMPILED FOR THE X64 PLATFORM, THE PROBLEM IS SOLVED.
ALSO PRESENTED THE PATH OUTSIDE THE FILE PATH WHILE COMPILING WITH X86 (32 BIT). (PROGRAM FILES 64 AND X86 FOLDERS)
MICROSOFT POSSIBLY MADE ERROR IN CODING WSCRIPT.EXE.

`File size: 167 KB`
`C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe` = I have tested. The gave the correct path.

`File size: 144 KB`
`C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wscript.exe` = I have tested. The gave an incorrect path.

However, there is an error. If you look at the file sizes you'll notice that the larger one is 64 bit. The locations of the Wscript.exe files seem to be assigned incorrectly. Bit control of wscript application was done with Process Explorer application.

`144 KB = 32 Bit`

`167 KB = 64 Bit`

SORRY FOR MY BAD ENGLISH.